# Locked question concerning contest problem

Tags: discussion, specific-question, contests, locked-posts

This question has come to my attention: [Prove this inequality with $xyz\le 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192440). It has been locked and it seems appropriate to make a meta post about it. I'm not requesting to unlock, I just think there should be a meta post about it.

Note that the OP has asked the same question [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1061692p4598524) and indeed it seems to be an Australian TST problem (if that's relevant).

The reason why the question is locked is not clear to me.

Comment: Do you think that every locked thread should have a meta post? (Not being facetious here, I'm honestly asking.)

Comment: Not when the reason is clear, I'd say. But I wonder how we're supposed to discuss about locked post.

Comment: Oh, it's fine, it's just that the sentence "I just think there should be a meta post about it" confused me a bit with this aspect. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There are several unclear points about this post. Nobody has been able to give a link to the Australian contest this is supposedly from. On the contrary, according to one commenter the cited contest only takes place in April. My other unanswered questions involve information only moderators have access to. If you can give a link to the contest where this problem was used, please share it with us. I will unlock it immediately, if given evidence that it is not from an ongoing contest. Have you googled "Australian TST 2015"?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Perhaps you intended to write "if given evidence that it is not from *a specific* ongoing contest"? Just to keep the onus on the lock requester in these cases.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Thanks. Something like that :-). Of course, no one can prove that this is not a problem in some ongoing contest somewhere. A link to a past contest where this was a problem would satisfy me! If somebody else is reusing it as a contest problem somewhere else? Well, that is the organizer's problem.

Comment: I also want to repeat the point that as a past participant and current organizer of local math contests I enforce our policy on contest questions with possibly too much zeal. Read: I lock first and ask questions later. As Lord_Farin suggested such requests need to be backed up with a link or other (possibly private) means. The present case is exceptional for other reasons.

Comment: As of right now at least, your AOPS link is broken (site is down due to maintenance).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I see nothing wrong with zeal that is meant to uphold fairness. After all, if the asker does not even provide the context of a question (why he/she thinks it is a question worth answering), other people cannot be blamed for any suspicions especially if the question smells like a contest problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't appear to be explicitly asking a question, but I assume that the final paragraph is the implicit question which you want answered. I think that [math SE contest problem policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16775/5676) will answer that satisfactorily.